# Is there a way to run Espresso test with multiple test methods but only one setup method?

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I have a simple test today:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class WhenNavigatingToUsersView {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = 
        new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Before
    public void setActivity() {
        mainActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.icon), hasSibling(withText(R.string.users)))).perform(click());
    }

    @Test
    public void thenCorrectViewTitleShouldBeShown() {
        onView(withText("This is the Users Activity.")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void thenCorrectUserShouldBeShown() {
        onView(withText("Donald Duck (1331)")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

But for every test method the `setActivity` is run, which, if you have 10-15 methods, in the end will be time consuming (if you have a lot of views too).

`@BeforeClass` doesn't seem to work since it has to be static and thus forcing the `ActivityTestRule` to be static as well.

So is there any other way to do this? Rather than having multiple asserts in the same test method?

Answer (score 4):

`@Before` annotation should only precede methods containing preliminary setup. Initialization of needed objects, getting the current session or the current activity, you get the idea.

It is replacing the old `setUp()` method from the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, just as `@After` replaces the `tearDown()`.
That means that **it is intended to be executed before every test in the class and it should stay that way.**

You should have no `ViewInteraction`, no `DataInteraction`, no `Assertions` nor `View` actions in this method, since that is not its purpose.

In your case, simply remove the `onView()` call from `setActivity()` and put it inside the actual test methods, in every test method if necessary, like so:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class WhenNavigatingToUsersView {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = 
        new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Before
    public void setActivity() {
        mainActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        // other required initializations / definitions
    }

    @Test
    public void thenCorrectViewTitleShouldBeShown() {
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.icon), hasSibling(withText(R.string.users)))).perform(click());
        onView(withText("This is the Users Activity.")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void thenCorrectUserShouldBeShown() {
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.icon), hasSibling(withText(R.string.users)))).perform(click());
        onView(withText("Donald Duck (1331)")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You kind of missing my point... Is there a way not to have to define view interaction for every test method? A good unit test for me is that a test method should only have one assert per test and the setup be made in another method. Consider this view would be full of fields I want to verify if they exist, it would be very expensive to interact with the view for every test. When I only want to "open" that view once and perform multiple tests.

Comment: Why should I not have view interaction and other stuff in setActivity? A better name would be setupContext or something and add all the prerequisites to the test there. That's the intention of the @Before  keyword in junit...

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you would be separating these tests.

Clicking on the user's icon will be in the HomeActivity test class while the rest of the tests will be in the UserActivity test class.

UserActivity test class will launch UserActivity with the proper Intent ( you can do so by passing the false Boolean into the Rule constructor and calling `launchActivity(intent)` manually).

This will eliminate the necessity of setting up the activity every single time. It will also get rid of constant dependency on the main activity. If something goes wrong, your UserActivity tests will be intact and will produce the results, while the issue will be caught by the test in the MainActivity.

Actually, by doing so your tests will might become MediumSize as the runtime will drastically decrease.

Comment: I could probably to something like that. But UsersActivity is not an activity, it's a fragment. I only have one activity so far; MainActivity. And all navigation goes to different fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
**** Setting ****
public void testStory() throws Exception {

}

public void testStory2() throws Exception {

}

public void testStory3() throws Exception {

}
```

Try to run your test by this command:

```
./gradlew cC
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it as follows or a minor variation of it to suit your needs:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);
private MainActivity mainActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();

@BeforeClass
public static void setActivity() {
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.icon), hasSibling(withText(R.string.users)))).perform(click());
}
```

This way, you 'mainActivity' need not be static. Also, the `setActivity()` method will get called only once.